# Do the tables under the same database use the same partitioning scheme?

Tags: database-partitioning, dolphindb

As mentioned in the question, the concept of database partitioning in DolphinDB is based on the database rather than on the table. Do the tables under the same database use the same partitioning scheme? If I need a different partition scheme, is creating a new database the only way?

Answer (score 0):

(1) The concept of database partitioning in DolphinDB is based on libraries rather than tables. The tables under the same library all use the same partitioning scheme.

(2) Different partition schemes are required, and different libraries need to be created.